# Solving a recurrence relation to show a series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinity

We are given the given sequence:

$$ x_1 = 1$$ and for all positive integers $n \ge 2 $ :

$$ n (x_n)^2 - x_{n-1} - n = 0 $$ where $ x_n \ge 0$ for all $ n \ge 1 $

We are supposed to find the limit as $ n \to \infty $ of $x_n$ and hence show that the series sum diverges as we sum up to infinity.

I noticed that as the terms go on and on, the value of $x_n$ gets closer to $1$.

Furthermore, I was able to manipulate the relation to arrive at:

$$ x_n = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n} \ x_{n-1}} $$

So I need to show that as $ n \to \infty $, the term $ \frac{x_{n-1}}{n} $ tends to $0$.

However, I was stuck at this part and I cannot seem to proceed further. Any help on this problem and/or alternative approaches will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you can show by induction that $x_n\leq 2$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we have $x_n\ge0$. We also have the somewhat trivial upper bound given from

$$x_n\le\sqrt{1+x_{n-1}}$$

as well as the inductively applied inequalities

$$x\le\varphi\implies\sqrt{1+x}\le\sqrt{1+\varphi}=\varphi$$

where $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is the golden ratio. Since it is bounded we have the results from the squeeze theorem

$$0\le\frac{x_{n-1}}n\le\frac\varphi n\to0$$

implying that

$$x_n\to\sqrt{1+0}=1$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ah this answer truly fits your profile name, it certainly is a work of art. I was able to devise another method to solve this question after looking at your answer, so thank you very much!